# Future[Either[A, B]] to Future[Either[A, C]] using a (B => Future[C]) function

Tags: scala, future, either

I've got a `Future[Either[A, B]]` and a function providing a `Future[C]` from a `B`.

I need to transform the `Future[Either[A, B]]` to `Future[Either[A, C]]`.

Is there a direct way to get the `Future[Either[A, C]]` and not a `Future[Either[A, Future[C]]]`?

I'm thinking about something like:

```
val eventuallyInitialValue: Future[Either[A, B]] = ???
val result: Future[Either[A, C]] = for {
  e: Either[A, B] <- initialValue
  c: C <- service.getValue(e.right)
} yield e.right.map(_ => c)
```

It's just pseudo-code since `service.getValue(e.right)` does not compile. What would be the correct way of doing it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is what I came up with:

```
type B = Int
type A = String
type C = Long
val eitherF: Future[Either[A, B]] = ???
def f(b: B): Future[C] = ???

val mapped: Future[Either[A, C]] = eitherF.flatMap {
  case Left(a) =>
    Future.successful(Left(a))
  case Right(b) =>
    f(b).map(Right(_))
}
```

Basically you can `flatMap` the future and then if it's a left just return the success, if it's a right you can apply the future and map a `Right` to it.

Answer (score 6):

Here is scalaz solution. Note that it uses scalaz version of either.

```
class A 
class B 
class C 

val initial: Future[A \/ B] = (new B).right.point[Future] 
val f: B => Future[C] = _ => (new C).point[Future] 

val result: Future[A \/ C] = (for {
                                e   <- EitherT(initial)
                                res <- EitherT(f(e).map(_.right))
                              } yield res).run
```

It is basically the same what @Ende Neu did but the matching and rewrapping is hidden in monad transformer.

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler to `initial.flatMap(_.fold(identity, (Right.apply _) compose f)` ?

Comment: It doesn't compile for me, and I am not sure if it can work but if it does it looks interesting and maybe you should post it as an answer.

Comment: You're right, the type is wrong; you need to map `Right` over the result of `f`

Answer (score 3):

You can do this by lifting the `B => Future[C]` function into an `Either[E, B] => Future[Either[E, C]]` function and then you can `flatMap` on the original future.

```
eventuallyInitialValue.flatMap {
  case Left(e) => Future.successful(Left(e))
  case Right(r) => bToFC(r).map(Right.apply _)
}
```

Comment: Thanks. It just needs to be returned as a Right: bToFC(r).map(Right(_))

Comment: If you use `Future.successful` instead of `Future.apply` you will avoid creating `Left(e)` on a thread pool.

Answer (score 1):

Cats currently has [an open pull request](https://github.com/typelevel/cats/pull/999) to add a method `semiflatMap` to `OptionT` and `XorT` which takes a function `B => F[C]`.

We could create a similar function for `scalaz.EitherT` :

```
import scalaz._, Scalaz._

def semiFlatMap[F[_]: Monad, A, B, C](e: EitherT[F, A, B])(f: B => F[C]): EitherT[F, A, C] = 
  e.flatMap(f andThen EitherT.right[F, A, C])
```

Then you could do :

```
import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

val futureEither: Future[Either[String, Int]] = Future.successful(Right(1))
val f: Int => Future[Long] = i => Future.successful(i + 1L)

val appliedF: EitherT[Future,String,Long] = 
  semiFlatMap(EitherT.fromEither(futureEither))(f)

val futureEither2: Future[Either[String, Long]] = appliedF.run.map(_.toEither)
```